# Why isn't my rails controller/form persisting any data to my local database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, model, controller

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and as my first project I'm creating a beta sign-up page for my startup. I just want to save the users email address to a database for future use, and I am not able to persist any data into my database. I can add emails through the rails console, but my form/controller are not working. What's wrong?

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness:
 {case_sensitive: false }

end
```

User Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def index

  end



  def create
    User.create params[:email]

    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Success!"


  end

end
```

Home page HTML:

```
<h1>######</h1>
<p>Welcome to #####! Give us your email address, and we'll keep you informed on our
latest happenings.
You'll also be placed on the list for our private alpha and beta testings.</p>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

Form Partial:

```
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: paste the lines from the webrick output in the terminal window after you hit submit and tell me what it says.  I believe the problem is uniqueness: true.  You're missing the true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
User.create params[:email]
```

It should be:

```
User.create params[:user]
```

Comment: That did the trick. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

First, create the user with `params[:user]` not `params[:email]`. If you want just the email address, put `params[:user][:email]`.

This is because params is a nested hash and looks like this:
`params[:user] = { email: "name@example.com" }`.

Second, use conditional logic in case the email address does not pass validation and doesn't save.

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
  redirect_to :back, :notice => "Success!"
else
  # display error messages
end
```

or if you want to get verbose:

```
@user = User.new(:email => params[:user][:email])
```